# Less (CSS) calculations are not being evaluated when executed in a gulp task

Tags: css, gulp, less, gulp-less

I'm working with LESS files, and using gulp to compile the CSS. I've noticed that calculations are not being evaluated.

For example, the following less...

```
.footer-bar {   
    a {
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: @grid-gutter-width / 2;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

... is appearing in the CSS file as...

```
.footer-bar a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px / 2;    /* <-- UNEVALUATED */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the gulp setup...

```
function compileLessFile(path) {
    return gulp.src(`./${path}`)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefixer("last 1 ie version"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
}

function watchLessChanges() {
    console.info("Watching .less files for changes...");
    gulp.watch(`${paths.watchableDirs}/*.less`).on("change", (path) => compileLessFile(path));
};

exports.default = watchLessChanges;
```

Can anyone explain why these calculations are left unresolved by `gulp-less`?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I set `gulp-less` and `gulp-autoprefixer` back to previous versions then it worked.

I *was* using...

- `gulp-less` ^5.0.0
- `gulp-autoprefixer` ^8.0.0

I put these back to...

- `gulp-less` 4.0.1
- `gulp-autoprefixer` 7.0.1

... and the problem went away.